# How to decode Chinese characters in while exporting to CSV from views data export module?

Tags: views, 8, importing-exporting

I have used [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module for CSV exporting in views. It works fine but its not able to decode non-latin languages. I didn't find any configuration also in views data export settings. Only it has pre-selected UTF-8 configuration. Can anyone faced this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have mbstring enabled?

Comment: mbstring is enabled but "HTTP input encoding translation" is disabled. Is this also should be enabled?